# Attempting to remove an Element at specific location in user-defined Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This is from an old homework problem, that I already turned in, but I wasn't able to figure it out.  I'm trying to remove an element from my LinkedList at a specific index using my user-defined class.  Below is the pseudo code I'm working off of, but it doesn't have the same parameters as mine so I tried modifying it, but had an issue.  I'm a programming noob (roughly 6 months of experience), just FYI.  I understand ArrayLists just fine, but LinkedLists have been giving me trouble.

```
/*
 * Remove the nth element in the list.  The first element is element 1.
 * Return the removed element to the caller.

    function remove(List list, Node node)
        if node.prev == null
            list.firstNode := node.next
        else
            node.prev.next := node.next
        if node.next == null
            list.lastNode := node.prev
        else
            node.next.prev := node.prev
        destroy node
 */
```

My method asks the user to enter an index position to delete.  Because an int and LinkEntry are different types, naturally I'm having issues.  I don't know how to incorporate the int that is passed through the parameter.

```
public void remove(int n)
{
    LinkEntry<E> remove_this = new LinkEntry<E>();
    remove_this.element = n;

    for (remove_this = head; remove_this != null; remove_this = remove_this.next)
    {
        //removes the head if list is only 1 item long
        if (head.next == null)
            head = remove_this.next;
        else
            //sets previous element to the next element
            remove_this.previous.next = remove_this.next;

        //if nothing comes after remove_this, then remove the tail element
        if (remove_this.next == null)
            tail = remove_this.previous;
        else
            //sets next previous element to current previous element
            remove_this.next.previous = remove_this.previous;  
    }
}
```

If you know of anywhere that gives another example that is more similar to what I'm trying to solve I would really appreciate it.  I've looked through my text and online, but no luck.

Comment: [offtopic] "The first element is element 1." - Ouch!

Comment: @Fildor Should it not be?  I'm still very new to this and don't know the best practices yet.

Comment: In most languages indexes start at 0. That's also called "zero-based". For beginners it's often a bit confusing to refer to the first element as number "0" but it has a lot of advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a counter to zero, browse your linked list from its first element (apparently named "head"), and increment the counter until its equal to n (or you reached the end of the list).

When counter equals to n, you must connect previous entry to next, and next to previous (so it deconnects the Nth). You also have to take care of special cases, when n=1 (you're supposed to delete "head" entry, that is to say set head to head.next), when next is null (n = list length), and when n negative or greater than list length.

Answer (score 0):

When I learned this in galaxy far, far away ... it helped me to paint it on paper. Something like this:

You have

```
              A       B       C
 next         *------>*------>*---->NULL
 prev NULL<---*<------*-------*
```

and you want

```
              A       C       
 next         *------>*---->NULL
 prev NULL<---*<------*
```

So if you find B, you know what to do. But how to find B? B is the second element in our example above, so we'll be given a "1" in zero-based lists or a "2" in one-based lists. 
A typical scenario would be to hold a reference to the first element of the list. This is often referred to as the "head". Now you would start with that head and follow its `next`-pointer. What do you get? The second element in the list. In our example that would already be our "B". Notice, that we followed `next` 1 time ... now assume we were to delete C. We got index 2 ( or one-based: 3) , we startet with head, followed `next` 1 time and got B. 1<2 so follow `next` again. Notice that we have to follow B's next instead of "head"'s So if using a loop, we'll have to use some sort of local var. Now we have the 2nd Element, which is C and remove it. Notice that C's "next" is `null`. So we are done in that direction.

Comment: So in my code above, my local variable for my loop would be remove_this, but how do I set n = remove_this if n is of type int and remove_this is of type E?

Comment: You'll have to hold a reference to the element under inspection **and** a count variable. That way you can in each iteration increment the count and update the element var.